# Removing an item from a WinJS.Binding.List

Tags: javascript, windows-8, winjs

I looked at the Controls_ListViewWorkingWithDataSources MSDN sample to see how to remove an item from a WinJS.Binding.List and here's their solution. Please tell me there's an easier way.

```
if (list2.selection.count() > 0) {
    list2.selection.getItems().done(function (items) {

        //Sort the selection to ensure its in index order
        items.sort(function CompareForSort(item1, item2) {
            var first = item1.index, second = item2.index;
            if (first === second) {
                return 0;
            }
            else if (first < second) {
                return -1;
            }
            else {
                return 1;
            }
        });

        //Work backwards as the removal will affect the indices of subsequent items
        for (var j = items.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            // To remove the items, call splice on the list, passing in a count and no replacements
            lettersList.splice(items[j].index, 1);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid the getItems() call and the then block by using:`iSelection.getIndices();`. [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh872197.aspx) gives you an array with the indices you need to remove.

So the code would be more like this. Haven't tested this.

```
// nothing in docs guarantees these are returned in sorted order, so we need to sort
var indicesList = list2.selection.getindices().sort(function(a,b){return a-b}); 
for (var j = indicesList .length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
    // To remove the items, call splice on the list, passing in a count and no replacements
    lettersList.splice(indicesList[j], 1);
}
```

Encapsulate it into a utily class like this:

```
function deleteSelectedItemsFromList(selection, list) {
    var indicesList = selection.getIndices().sort(function(a,b){return a-b}); 
    for (var j = indicesList .length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        // To remove the items, call splice on the list, passing in a count and no replacements
        list.splice(indicesList[j], 1);
    }
}
```

Call like this:

```
Utils.deletedSelectedItemsFromList(listview.selection, listViewList);
```

Bam, you've got a one liner.

Answer (score 1):

The code to remove the item in the MSDN sample is more complex because it supports deleting multiple items from a list when those items might not be in consecutive order. Note where they retrieve all of the currently selected items in the list by use of `list2.selection.getItems()` in their code. For example, given a list containing [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0], the MSDN sample code would allow the user to multi-select and delete items 1,2,4,7,9 leaving [3,5,6,8,0] in the list.

If all you want to do is delete a single item from a WinJS.Binding.List (or multiple consecutive items), you can accomplish this with a single call to WinJS.Binding.List.splice() and skip all the extra code in the MSDN sample.

Comment: I am removing multiple items.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the remove method on the datasource, so same thing but longer :)  :

```
if (list2.selection.count() > 0) {
    list2.selection.getItems().done(function (items) {

    //Sort the selection to ensure its in index order
    items.sort(function CompareForSort(item1, item2) {
        var first = item1.index, second = item2.index;
        if (first === second) {
            return 0;
        }
        else if (first < second) {
            return -1;
        }
        else {
            return 1;
        }
    });

    //Work backwards as the removal will affect the indices of subsequent items
    for (var j = items.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {

             var _dataSource = list2.itemDataSource;
             //Start the sequence of edits
             _dataSource.beginEdits();

             //Get new Items that will be added to the existing item source
             var newItems = { "id": selection[i].data.id, "name": selection[i].data.name };
             //remove the last item
             _dataSource.remove(_dataSource.itemFromIndex(indicesList[j])._value.key);

             //YOU CAN EVEN ADD A NEW ITEM IF YOU WANT
             //_dataSource.insertAtStart(null, newItems);

             //Ends the batch of edits
             _dataSource.endEdits();

    }
});

}
```