# A method to add an element to a ListView

Tags: javascript, windows-store-apps

Is there a method to add an element to a ListView? My goal is to do this without binding data! For example:

```
     myListView.add("one");
     myListView.add("two");
```

ecc

Comment: There is very little information!!! What is your listview there, ...?

Comment: My listview is exactly the same as shown here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/windows/apps/hh465496.aspx

Comment: It seems it isn't designed in order to add elements after initialisation if you check at the method list : http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/windows/apps/br211837.aspx#methods ...

Comment: @SamuelCaillerie you are looking at the list, not the underlying data source : ) Check out (well see post below as well): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700774.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just simply add the item to your initial list. If you have binding setup, this happens automatically.

Html

```
<div id="simpleBinding" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView"></div>

<div id="simpleBindingTemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
    <h3 data-win-bind="innerText:name" />
    <span>Name :</span><span data-win-bind="textContent: name"></span>
    <img data-win-bind="src:imageUrl" />
</div>
```

Javascript

```
//Note you could also declare an object type to use here,
//and instantiate them in the list below 
var Person = WinJS.Binding.define({
    name: "",
    birthday: ""
});

//Using the above object
//var people = [
//    new Person({ name: "Bob", birthday: "2/2/2002" }),
//    new Person({ name: "Sally", birthday: "3/3/2003" }),
//    new Person({ name: "Fred", birthday: "2/2/2002" })
//];


//Or simply using JSON
var people = [{ name: 'mary', birthday: '1/1/2010' }, 
              { name: 'fred', birthday: '1/1/2012' }];

//create the binding wrapper
var simpleFriends = new WinJS.Binding.List(people);

//get the ref to your list view
var simpleListView = document.getElementById('simpleBinding').winControl;

//get your template
var simpleTemplate = document.getElementById('simpleBindingTemplate');

simpleListView.itemDataSource = simpleFriends.dataSource;
//can also set in the markup for this element
simpleListView.itemTemplate = simpleTemplate;


//add a new item. the binding update happens automatically
//Could use a Person object we defined
//simpleFriends.push(new Person({ name: "Dynamically added", birthday: "2/2/2002"}));

//or JSON
simpleFriends.push({ name: "Dynamically added", birthday: "2/2/2002"});
```

For removing items you can use pop or check out this post for an indexed approach
[Removing an item from a WinJS.Binding.List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13872703/removing-an-item-from-a-winjs-binding-list)

There's some good binding content on App Builder for 'Day 10' [App Builder](http://aka.ms/stackbuilder)

Comment: Thanks a lot, just a question: Where/How "Person" is declared?

Comment: woops, forgot the Person object definition which goes to show you can mix/match object types you add - IE you can .push() a different 'type' (although I use that term 'type' loosley here) than that which is already there because JavaScript is a loosely typed language. See edit above where I added some comments.

Comment: Is there a way to allow binding between WinRT objects and the BindingList along these lines? I'm struggling to find one.

Comment: I haven't tried but what about creating WinJS.Binding.List from one of those objects? If that doesn't work you could always enumerate the object and .push() to your winjs list.